# Button видна на переднем плане , хотя во весь экран белый RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

RelativeLayout с белым фоном занимает весь экран,но кнопка отображается поверх него.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:layout_width="229dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="154dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_for_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlError"
        android:layout_width="231dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:background="#ed6340"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/error_authorization"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="231dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rlError"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/rlError"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlError"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:hint="@string/hint_email"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
        android:layout_width="231dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etEmail"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAuthorization"
        android:layout_width="231dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="@string/btn_signin"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="@string/footer"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFooter"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlLoading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminate="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: screen]

Comment: На реальном девайсе/эмуляторе тоже самое? Или только в превью студии такое? Если последнее - считайте это багом превью и не обращайте внимания.

Comment: На api 21+ у кнопок это обычное поведение. Они игнорят порядок добавления в лейаут и всегда отображаются сверху. Один из вариантов `android:visibility="invisible"`. И обратно, когда нужно показать.